# FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #3

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-service

In my program there is a service that is responsible for positioning

```
public class GPSTracker extends Service implements LocationListener {

private final Context mContext;


//определяем переменную главного активити
    MainActivity ma;

    GPSTracker gps;
    Teleport_user_profile_activity UP;
    ReadData RD;
    PostData PD;

// flag for GPS status
boolean isGPSEnabled = false;

// flag for network status
boolean isNetworkEnabled = false;

// flag for GPS status
boolean canGetLocation = false;

Location location; // location
double latitude; // latitude
double longitude; // longitude

// The minimum distance to change Updates in meters
private static final long MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES = 10; // 10 meters

// The minimum time between updates in milliseconds
private static final long MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES = 1000 * 60 * 1; // 1 minute

// Declaring a Location Manager
protected LocationManager locationManager;

public GPSTracker(Context context) {
    this.mContext = context;
    getLocation();
}

public static String UserLoginFile;
public static String UserPassFile;
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Функция для определения местоположения
public Location getLocation() {
    try {
        locationManager = (LocationManager) mContext
                .getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

        // getting GPS status
        isGPSEnabled = locationManager
                .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

        // getting network status
        isNetworkEnabled = locationManager
                .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

        if (!isGPSEnabled && !isNetworkEnabled) {
            // no network provider is enabled
        } else {
            this.canGetLocation = true;
            if (isNetworkEnabled) {
                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                        LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,
                        MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                        MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                Log.d("Network", "Network");
                if (locationManager != null) {
                    location = locationManager
                            .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
                    if (location != null) {
                        latitude = location.getLatitude();
                        longitude = location.getLongitude();
                    }
                }
            }
            // if GPS Enabled get lat/long using GPS Services
            if (isGPSEnabled) {
                if (location == null) {
                    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                            LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                            MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                            MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                    Log.d("GPS Enabled", "GPS Enabled");
                    if (locationManager != null) {
                        location = locationManager
                                .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                        if (location != null) {
                            latitude = location.getLatitude();
                            longitude = location.getLongitude();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return location;
}

/**
 * Stop using GPS listener
 * Calling this function will stop using GPS in your app
 * */
public void stopUsingGPS(){
    if(locationManager != null){
        locationManager.removeUpdates(GPSTracker.this);
    }       
}

/**
 * Function to get latitude
 * */
public double getLatitude(){
    if(location != null){
        latitude = location.getLatitude();
    }

    // return latitude
    return latitude;
}

/**
 * Function to get longitude
 * */
public double getLongitude(){
    if(location != null){
        longitude = location.getLongitude();
    }

    // return longitude
    return longitude;
}

/**
 * Function to check GPS/wifi enabled
 * @return boolean
 * */
public boolean canGetLocation() {
    return this.canGetLocation;
}

/**
 * Function to show settings alert dialog
 * On pressing Settings button will lauch Settings Options
 * */
public void showSettingsAlert(){
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);

    // Setting Dialog Title
    alertDialog.setTitle("GPS is settings");

    // Setting Dialog Message
    alertDialog.setMessage("GPS is not enabled. Do you want to go to settings menu?");

    // On pressing Settings button
    alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Settings", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int which) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
            mContext.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    // on pressing cancel button
    alertDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        dialog.cancel();
        }
    });

    // Showing Alert Message
    alertDialog.show();
}



//события которые происходят если позиция поменялась
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    //Отправка местоположения если позиция изменилась 10_06_2013

    new PostData(gps, RD, getBaseContext()).execute();


}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
    return null;
}
```

And there AsynсTask that transmits position data and others to the server

```
class PostData extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
// GPSTracker class
    GPSTracker gps;
    Context rdContext;
//определяем переменную главного активити
    MainActivity ma;
    Teleport_user_profile_activity UP;
    ReadData RD;

    public PostData (GPSTracker gps, ReadData RD, Context c) {
        this.gps = gps;
        this.RD = RD;
        rdContext = c;

    }


    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // do stuff before posting data
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        postData();
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // do stuff after posting data
        super.onPostExecute(result);
    }

    public void postData() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
        //переводим значение double в стринг
        double latitudep = gps.getLatitude();
        double longitudep = gps.getLongitude();
        double totalLatitude = latitudep;
        double totalLongitude = longitudep;
        String stotalLatitude = String.valueOf(totalLatitude);
        String stotalLongitude = String.valueOf(totalLongitude);
        // временная переменная для определения времени устройства
        Time nowTime = new Time();
        nowTime.setToNow();
        String snowTime = String.valueOf(nowTime);
        //берем информацию о юзере
        RD = new ReadData(rdContext);
        String UserInfo = RD.readSavedDataLogin();
        String UserPass = RD.readSavedDataPass();
        //посылка данных на сервер
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://myheart.pp.ua/Android_in.php");

    try {
        // Add your data
        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(4);

        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("latitude", stotalLatitude));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("longitude", stotalLongitude));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Android_device_time", snowTime));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("user_info", UserInfo));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("user_pass", UserPass));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("separator", "______________________________________"));
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
        httpclient.execute(httppost);

        // Execute HTTP Post Request
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Sending data by manually on MainActivity is successful I call AsyncTask the following code

```
new PostData(gps, RD, getBaseContext()).execute();
```

But I need to send location automatically when user change position
I think that it needs to use the:

```
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    new PostData(gps, RD, getBaseContext()).execute();
}
```

But when i change position, I get an error

```
06-10 14:34:57.533: E/AndroidRuntime(1544): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #3
E/AndroidRuntime(1544): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
```

I can not understand what I'm doing wrong and how can I send data to the user's location automatically when user change its position

```
06-10 14:34:57.533: E/AndroidRuntime(1544): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #3
06-10 14:34:57.533: E/AndroidRuntime(1544): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
06-10 14:34:57.533: E/AndroidRuntime(1544):     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
06-10 14:34:57.533: E/AndroidRuntime(1544):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
06-10 14:34:57.533: E/AndroidRuntime(1544):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
06-10 14:34:57.533: E/AndroidRuntime(1544):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
06-10 14:34:57.533: E/AndroidRuntime(1544):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
06-10 14:34:57.533: E/AndroidRuntime(1544):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
06-10 14:34:57.533: E/AndroidRuntime(1544):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
06-10 14:34:57.533: E/AndroidRuntime(1544):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
06-10 14:34:57.533: E/AndroidRuntime(1544):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
06-10 14:34:57.533: E/AndroidRuntime(1544): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-10 14:34:57.533: E/AndroidRuntime(1544):     at com.teleport.saas.PostData.postData(PostData.java:65)
06-10 14:34:57.533: E/AndroidRuntime(1544):     at com.teleport.saas.PostData.doInBackground(PostData.java:50)
06-10 14:34:57.533: E/AndroidRuntime(1544):     at com.teleport.saas.PostData.doInBackground(PostData.java:1)
06-10 14:34:57.533: E/AndroidRuntime(1544):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
06-10 14:34:57.533: E/AndroidRuntime(1544):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
```

Comment: I think the error lies in the call to getBaseContext(). Can you try to pass mContext there?

Comment: mContext used in GPSTracker. if you mean getBaseContext() it rdContext this is my ReadData class. I need it to read data from a file. I try use mContext but I have same error

Comment: Can you expand your logcat? Meaning: are there more lines relating to the exception?

Comment: I add full logcat in my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't seem to be initializing the `gps` variable in your `GPSTracker` class. That's the reason for your `NPE`

Comment: I initializing gps in AsyncTask which I call them. or do I need to initialize it by another method?

Comment: if you mean you're initializing it at `this.gps = gps;` then you're actually just copying the value you're receiving from `GPSTracker`. And since you're not initializing that variable, you're trying to extract longitude and latitude from a null value.

Comment: Oh. I initializing GPSTracker gps = new GPSTracker(this); but the latitude and longitude zero for some reason.

Comment: I actually didn't mean that you should randomly initialize it. Rather in     `public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    new PostData(gps, RD, getBaseContext()).execute();
}` you need to assign the current location to your gps variable

Comment: Thank you very much for your support. I've only been studying programming for Android. But in the manual method when the procedure PostData I have taken the latest location of the user as PostData is a function gps.getLatitude() and getLongitude()